# Module Not Found - pyspark

Tags: pyspark, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to import pyspark but it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'" even though I just installed pyspark.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4G4a.png)

I was expecting it to import pyspark without any error.